# How to convert string into an array

Tags: php, arrays, explode, array-push

I have an array something like this

```
$arr1 = array(
    '0' => '674534856|213123213|232313123',
    '1' => '349578449|782374879|232313123'
);
```

I loop through the arr1 array,

```
for ($x=0; $x < $count; $x++) {
    $check = explode("|", $arr1[$x]);
    array_pop($check);

    $count_check = count($check);

    for ($z=0; $z < $count_check; $z++) {
        array_push($result, $check[$z]); 
    }  
}
```

It's not working as expected. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT** `$result` is result array

Comment: What's in `$result`? What is `$things`?

Comment: What exactly *do* you expect?

Comment: @BoltClock $result is result array. Sorry My mistake updated the question.

Comment: @ignacio I want something like this $result = array('674534856', '213123213', '232313123')

Comment: That's only one of the values. What of the other?

Comment: @Ivanka, is that not just `$result = explode('|', $arr1[0])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `implode()` everything in your input array with the same delimiter to flatten it to a single string, and then `explode()` by that delimiter:

```
$result = explode('|', implode('|', $arr1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$result = explode('|', join('|', $arr1));

// outputs
array('674534856', '213123213', '232313123', '349578449', '782374879', '232313123')
```

Or

```
$result = array_map(function($temp) { return explode('|', $temp); }, $arr1);

// outputs
array(
    [0] => array('674534856', '213123213', '232313123'), 
    [1] => array('349578449', '782374879', '232313123') 
)
```